# c# .netcore List all files under amazon s3 folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

Using C# and amazon .Net core, able to list all the files with in a amazon S3 folder as below:

```
      public async Task<string> GetMenuUrl(entities.Restaurant restaurant)
        {
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_appSettings.AWSPublicKey, _appSettings.AWSPrivateKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

        string imagePath;
        string restaurantName = trimSpecialCharacters(restaurant.Name);
        int restaurantId = restaurant.RestaurantId;
        ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
        ListObjectsResponse listResponse; 

        imagePath = $"Business_menu/{restaurantId}/";
        listRequest.BucketName = _appSettings.AWSS3BucketName;
        listRequest.Prefix = imagePath;
        do
        {
            listResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(listRequest);

        } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);

        var files = listResponse.S3Objects.Select(x => x.Key);
        var arquivos = files.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
        

        return arquivos.ToString();

    }
```

Currently arquivos returns a list containing both the images (image1.jpg, image2.jpg) which is as expected and then I return it as a string.

But when I go to call this method from another function.

```
       public async Task<VenueMenuResponse> GetVenueMenuUrl(int restaurantId)
        {

            var restaurant = await _context.Restaurant.Where(w => w.RestaurantId == restaurantId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            var result = await _storyService.GetMenuUrl(restaurant);

            var response = new MenuResponse() //just contains string variable called MenuUrl
            {
                MenuUrl = result
            };

            return response;
        }
```

It returns this:

```
{
    "menuUrl": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
}
```

When I want it to return

```
{
    "menuUrl": "Image1.jpg"
},
{
    "menuUrl": "Image2.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate thought `results` and return list of results.

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<VenueMenuResponse>> GetVenueMenuUrl(int restaurantId)
    {

        var restaurant = await _context.Restaurant.Where(w => w.RestaurantId == restaurantId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var result = await _storyService.GetMenuUrl(restaurant);

        var response = result.Select(e => new MenuResponse() //just contains string variable called MenuUrl
        {
            MenuUrl = e
        };

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: it's still showing the same response except it's broken down into a list

Comment: var result is still equal to "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: Must be with how it's being passed from the arquivos.ToString(); to GetVenueMenuUrl

Comment: The list contents seems to be outputting and object instead of the list content

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = string.Join(", ", fileName);
```

The default ToString() implementation of List simply prints the name of the type.

This magical line managed to solve things for me. The list was originally outputting just the object instead of the actual content of the list.